# How to retrieve common elements/words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a huge list of words (around 50K) stored in a db (I am using activerecord), that I would like to use and retrieve matching words against a chunk of text.

I am aware ruby provides Intersection

```
t = "this is a sample text, was created for demo"
w = ["is","a","was","to","and"] 

t.split & w #=> ["is", "a", "was"]
```

But how can I do it for 50K words? And the frequency of doing such a match is likely to be around 1000 times a day.

Comment: you should put that text in a global variable or cache so it reduce the time to hit DB repeatedly and can set a after update callback to update that global variable or cache when this text get updated in database

Answer (score 1):

How about using full text search engines for that? Here are some links:

1. [Thinking Sphinx](http://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/) gem for Sphinx search engine.
2. [RSolr](https://github.com/rsolr/rsolr) gem for Solr search engine.

I understand that it might be an overkill for your current task, but it's the most suitable and performant solution for more complex variants.